# Area of the region bounded by graphs of two exponentials.

Tags: calculus

1. Let S be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graphs of $y = e^{-x^2}$ and $y = 2x^2$, and the y axis.

a) Find the area of the region S.

So when I integrate, is it from 0 to .5931? I found where they intersect on the calculator. Is this the right method?

$\int(e^{-x^2} - 2x^2)$ then i'll plug in, then continue with the other parts of the question (volume/revolving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should integrate the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}-2x^2$ from $0$ to $0.593071$, where two graph intersects. That is approximately $0.391231$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way how do you integrate e^(-x^2)? I do the problem on my calculator and I get .3912 but I can't get there by hand.

Comment: The primitive of $e^{-x^2}$ is not an elementary function, so this cannot be integrated by hand anyway. See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra))

Comment: Ok thanks. And for clarification, the next part is to revolve around the x-axis. I know the equation for this and plugged it into my calculator and got 1.3205. Correct?

Comment: I think the integration now should be $\int_{0}^{0.59} \pi(e^{-x^2}-2x^2)^2dx=0.978763$. How do you get $0.4203$?

Comment: I was taught: V= π ∫((e^−(x^2))^2−(2x^2)^2 dx (with the interval, not sure how to make it code)

Comment: So basically I was taught to multiply pi after integrating and you did it inside

Comment: OK, sorry that I was wrong, you are correct!